# "Page can't be displayed" and Admin must enter credentials for local app domain (DNS is correct I think!)

Tags: sharepoint-addin, authentication, app, sharepoint-hosted-app, credentials

SharePoint Server is a Windows Server 2012 R2 and contains the Active Directory, SharePoint and SQL Server 2008.

Local domain is: `test.local`
SharePoint host name is: `sharepoint` (in domain `sharepoint.test.local`)
App domain: `apps.test.local`

Everything is configured like the MSDN information - I think.

[image: Configuration of DNS Server]

If I open the site collection everything works like expected.
As Administrator I get an error during the app installation.
As another User I can install the app successfully.

If I click on the app as an Administrator I get this. But after entering credentials I get the same message each time. At the end its an Authorization error.

If I click on the app as a other User (which is in Administrator group and site collection primary administrator).

[image: View as administrator and user]

I really don't know what's wrong.
Everything should be configured as in MSDN tutorials :(

Thanks in Advance for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing: your DNS record is probably misconfigured. The alias `*.apps.test.local` should point to `SharePoint.test.local` (i.e. the FQDN of the SharePoint server). You must have `sharepoint.test.local` in the column "data" of the first screenshot (i.e. enter `sharepoint.test.local` in the textbox "Flly qualified domain name (FQDN) for target host).

Also, note that "System Account" (and your Administrator account is probably System Account) cannot install/uninstall apps in SharePoint, so that's is expected.

Comment: Hmm I tried this but ping works, too. And as the "TEST\Administrator" I see that the internet explorer is asking for credentials. (I don't know why) As the User I see "Page can't be displayed". So I don't know why there is this big difference. But I'll try again your information and reply the result. But before I configured instead a CNAME a A Record and this didn't works, too. And in one tutorial there was described to use the CNAME for the whole domain as in the picture above.

Comment: `ALIAS (CNAME)` is what you need. And for sure, it must be defined as a pointer to `sharepoint.test.local`.

Comment: No it doesn't work :( I restarted the server but still not work. Forwarded Lookup Zones "apps.test.local". Name: "*", Type "Alias (CNAME)", Data: "sharepoint.test.local." Timestamp: "static". Hmm. And I restarted the whole server after changing. :/